# How do I make a button do a specific .java file in eclipse

Tags: java

So im trying to make this program for my friends where it gives u a random alt (email and password) for Minecraft. I have figured out a way to give a random email and password but i need a gui to open showing the password and email. Is there any way to code a button to do it?

My current code for the random alt is

```
public class NameGenerator {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] names = {"email", "email"};
    int index = (int) (Math.random() * names.length);
    String name = names[index];
    System.out.println("Your random alt is " + name + " Have Fun and also DM me on Discord if this alt does not work @________#0000!");
    }
}
```

Comment: [Getting start with JavaFX](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/get_started/jfxpub-get_started.htm) or [Creating a GUI with Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html)

Comment: You have to do some research before you ask a question. Otherwise we don't know what you're having difficulty with and are just writing code for you.

Comment: Im trying to create a gui that can run on a .jar file that can run the above code and display it on the gui. Like how do i edit what the button does if u tell me how i can probably solve it myself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java SWING can be used here. See if you are looking for something like below code

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame f=new JFrame();  

    JButton b=new JButton("Get Password");  
    b.setBounds(50,120,120,30);  

    b.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){  
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){  

            String[] names = {"email", "email"};
            int index = (int) (Math.random() * names.length);
            String name = names[index];
            String msg = "Your random alt is " + name + " Have Fun and also DM me on Discord if this alt does not work @________#0000!";

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(f, msg);
        }  
    });  

    f.add(b);
    f.setSize(400,400);  
    f.setLayout(null);  
    f.setVisible(true);   
}
```

Comment: YES, Thanks so much for the help, i didnt use all the code but i figured it out thanks!!!

Comment: @PandemicFTW plz accept the answer if it solved your purpose :-)

Answer (score 0):

Do you know how to create GUI in java? No? There are very simple and easy tutorials on how. Find one. Create a button. Double click the button and it will take you to a generated button `ActionListener` or something alike. Write inside what you want it to do.